# R: How to generate a xy plot with multiple discrete y against x

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I have a data frame like this now.

```
df <-data.frame("networkNO"=c(1:length(dg)),"AverageDegree"=average_degree,"AverageBetweenness"=average_betweenness,"AverageCloseness"=average_closeness,"ClusterCoefficient"=cluster_coefficient)
```

So each column shows a measure of a series of networks.

```
       networkNO AverageDegree AverageBetweenness AverageCloseness ClusterCoefficient
1          1     10.804124         300.453608     0.0012898154          0.4388075
2          2     10.785714          31.660714     0.0085438562          0.4646219
3          3     10.909091          52.688312     0.0055827873          0.4440915
4          4     10.000000          19.435897     0.0131519596          0.5078864
5          5     11.372014        1348.049488     0.0003100285          0.4193862
6          6      8.736842          66.210526     0.0054046865          0.5077356
7          7      1.000000           0.000000     1.0000000000                NaN
8          8      7.755102          49.346939     0.0070593456          0.5193906
9          9      9.000000           6.363636     0.0298526499          0.5279429
10        10      7.538462           2.230769     0.0611896445          0.6666667
11        11      7.297297          34.027027     0.0099660321          0.5391566
12        12      1.000000           0.000000     1.0000000000                NaN
13        13      6.666667          20.111111     0.0156903046          0.5445378
14        14      3.000000           0.000000     0.3333333333          1.0000000
15        15      9.658537          21.341463     0.0122712462          0.4870849
16        16      7.100000           8.050000     0.0290803614          0.5692964
```

I want to generate a 2-d plot with x-axis shows different measurements, y-axis shows actual measures.

How can I achieve it?
And how can I generate a boxplot?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to plot. What do you mean by "different measurements" and "actual measures"

Comment: Measurements means AverageDegree, AverageBetweenness, etc. And Y axis shows their value discretely

Comment: Because of the different scales (0-13000, 0-1) it's hard to do this on one plot. Can you rescale each measurement by the maximum value in that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
boxplot(df[-1])  ## exclude column `networkNO`
```

[image]

However, you have to **rescale your data**. At the moment, these columns differ so much in scale, and it is a bad idea to plot them directly on a box plot (like the figure above).

The following code will rescale your columns and update `df`:

```
df1 <- within(df, {AverageDegree = scale(AverageDegree);
                   AverageBetweenness = scale(AverageBetweenness);
                   AverageCloseness = scale(AverageBetweenness);
                   ClusterCoefficient = scale(ClusterCoefficient);})

boxplot(df1[-1])  ## exclude column `networkNO`
```

[image]

The default method in `scale` (see `?scale`) first centres data by subtracting mean, then divides data by standard deviation. You might think twice whether this is what you want, as after rescaling, the meaning of the value on `y-axis` has been slightly different.

If you don't want any kind of scaling, then you may need to consider **plotting a separate box plot for each column**, and arrange them in the same panel. The following does this:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
boxplot(df$AverageDegree, xlab = "AverageDegree")
boxplot(df$AverageBetweenness, xlab = "AverageBetweenness")
boxplot(df$AverageCloseness, xlab = "AverageCloseness")
boxplot(df$ClusterCoefficient, xlab = "ClusterCoefficient")
```

[image]

Note that `boxplot()` has a special argument `outline`. By setting `outline = FALSE`, outliers (unusually large data) will be removed. You can compare:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
boxplot(df$AverageDegree, xlab = "AverageDegree", outline = FALSE)
boxplot(df$AverageBetweenness, xlab = "AverageBetweenness", outline = FALSE)
boxplot(df$AverageCloseness, xlab = "AverageCloseness", outline = FALSE)
boxplot(df$ClusterCoefficient, xlab = "ClusterCoefficient", outline = FALSE)
```

[image]

**follow up**

> How can I plot dot plot instead of boxplot?

We can simply use `plot()`:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(rep(1, nrow(df)), df$AverageDegree, xlab = "AverageDegree", xaxt = "n")
plot(rep(1, nrow(df)), df$AverageBetweenness, xlab = "AverageBetweenness", xaxt = "n")
plot(rep(1, nrow(df)), df$AverageCloseness, xlab = "AverageCloseness", xaxt = "n")
plot(rep(1, nrow(df)), df$ClusterCoefficient, xlab = "ClusterCoefficient", xaxt = "n")
```

[image]

Maybe you are also interested in making histograms?

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
hist(df$AverageDegree, main = "AverageDegree", xlab = "")
hist(df$AverageBetweenness, main = "AverageBetweenness", xlab = "")
hist(df$AverageCloseness, main = "AverageCloseness", xlab = "")
hist(df$ClusterCoefficient, main = "ClusterCoefficient", xlab = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! How can I plot dot plot instead of boxplot? Take average degree as x axis and values as y axis?